# EXTJS Ext.Window Scroll

Tags: extjs

I have a couple of pop up boxes in my page which are basically ext.window. I am trying to set autoScroll:true for them but it doesnt show the scroll bars. Here is the code for one of the pop up's. Please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
windowTerms = new Ext.Window({
    autoWidth: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    header: false,
    closable: false,
    modal: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    frame: false,
    border: false,
    html: html
}); windowTerms.show();

}

function window_termspopClose() {
windowTerms.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try providing a height and width to the window.